# How do I follow multiple select Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: support, tag-filters

I find numerous of the Stack Exchange sites to be fascinating and I'd love to follow their questions. I'd also like all of these questions to be aggregated on one page, so I can follow them more easily. I'm thinking of something in terms of reddit subreddits.

Is that at all possible, or am I just thinking of the sites through the wrong paradigm?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do that using [filters](https://stackexchange.com/filters).  [Here I have set up an example filter to browse all questions from Gaming.SE, Programmers.SE, and Askubuntu.com.](https://stackexchange.com/filters/25892/demo-filter)

Click on "My Filters" and then on that big orange "New Filter" button to get started.